# Mock Third party library (Razorpay) in Angular Unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, sinon

I am trying to test a function in one of my component which consists following two lines:

```
this.rzp1 = new Razorpay(orderDetails);
this.rzp1.open();
```

I am trying to understand how to mock Razorpay in my test cases for this function.

This is how I am declaring Razorpay in my component:

```
export declare var Razorpay: any;
```

I have already tried various methods like:

```
var stub = sinon.createStubInstance(MyConstructor)
```

Any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use jasmine's built in spy facility instead of relying on another library (sinon)?

In your before each block, you can do something like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jasmine.spyOnAllFunctions(Razorypay.prototype);
  Razorypay.prototype.open.and.returnValue('foo');
});
```

You can find more information about [`spyOnAllFuntions` in the documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/global.html#spyOnAllFunctions).